# DateDiff of Logtable Dates Which Have The Same Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2012 I need to get the `datediff` of all dates in a Log table which has the same column, for example:

```
ID      | Version   |  Status   |   Date
-----------------------------------------------------
12345   |   1       |  new      |   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000
12345   |   2       |  up       |   2014-05-02 00:00:00.000
12345   |   3       |  appr     |   2014-05-03 00:00:00.000
67890   |   1       |  new      |   2014-05-04 00:00:00.000
67890   |   2       |  up       |   2014-05-08 00:00:00.000
67890   |   3       |  rej      |   2014-05-13 00:00:00.000
```

I need to get the date diff of all sequential dates (date between 1, 2 and date between 2, 3)

I have tried creating a while but with no luck!

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected output for above data

Comment: use `lag` or `lead` window function

Comment: I would recommend OUTER APPLY - use the second query in OUTER APPLY to select the record you know you are interested in, then in the first part of your query calculate the date difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way with OUTER APPLY (get the previous value) :

```
SELECT  t.*,
        DATEDIFF(day,p.[Date],t.[Date]) as dd
FROM YourTable t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ID = t.ID AND [DATE] < t.[Date] AND [Version] < t.[Version]
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
    ) as p
```

Output:

```
ID      Version Status  Date                    dd
12345   1       new     2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
12345   2       up      2014-05-02 00:00:00.000 1
12345   3       appr    2014-05-03 00:00:00.000 1
67890   1       new     2014-05-04 00:00:00.000 NULL
67890   2       up      2014-05-08 00:00:00.000 4
67890   3       rej     2014-05-13 00:00:00.000 5
```

Note: If you are using SQL Server 2012 then better use LEAD and LAG functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I group it by ID? any ideas?

Comment: What exactly you want to group?

Comment: You can put the results in to sub-query and SELECT ID, sum(DD) from (...) as p GROUP BY ID, or whatever you need

Comment: How can I re-write the above query in Oracle 10g? since they don't have "Outer Join", Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle. Maybe you can adopt TheGameiswar answer?

Comment: Tried with no luck so far

Answer (score 3):

This Calculates DateDiff as per your query "date diff of all sequential dates",if not sequential,it will just show same date.Further please don't use Reserved Keywords as Column names

```
SELECT ID,
[VERSION],
[STATUS],
[DATE],
CASE WHEN LEAD([DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [VERSION])=DATEADD(DAY,1,[DATE])
THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,[DATE],LEAD([DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY VERSION))  AS VARCHAR(5))
 ELSE [DATE] END AS DATEDIFFF
FROM
#TEMP
```